# An Array of Objects when imported in react native gives keys and values in double commas whereas no commas are required for key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would really appreciate if someone can help resolving this issue.

I created an array in separate sheet to pass on the labels, values and images for a drop down selection.

Categories.js

```
export const categoriesListData = [
  {
    label: "Chocolates & Snacks",
    value: "Chocolates & Snacks",
    icon: require("../assets/CategoriesStack/chocolatesandSnacks.png")
  },
  {
    label: "Baby Products",
    value: "Baby Products",
    icon: require("../assets/CategoriesStack/babyproducts.png")
  }
]
```

When I import my above sheet in main component, the console.log gives data in the below format:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "icon": 46,
    "label": "Chocolates & Snacks",
    "value": "Chocolates & Snacks",
  },
  Object {
    "icon": 47,
    "label": "Baby Products",
    "value": "Baby Products",
  },
```

However, I need the data in exact original way where label, value and icon is without `""`.

My import "Categories" use in component is:

```
 import { categoriesListData } from "../assets/categoriesConst";

  <CategoriesLList data={categoriesListData} />

function CategoriesLList({ data }) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    **const [items, setItems] = useState(data);**
    console.log(data);
  
    return (
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}
      />
    );
  }
```

Please tell what is the best way to handle such a thing as I believe there will be lots of server passing data too in such format, how best to handle such things.

Comment: Your data is valid and when you use items[0].value you would not see quotes. How is your data parsed? Json.parse() or something else?

Comment: the problem i am facing is the Key , it is coming as "label" : "chocolate", the dropdown select list need label: "chocolate".  the key should not have commas ""

Comment: I suspect a `JSON.stringify` somewhere is causing this issue.

Comment: how to Unstingify it then? any help?

Comment: JASON.PARSE() does not work.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. The provided snippets do not generate the output that you are describing. We can only speculate until you provide more details.

Comment: @DavidScholz have you seen this type of imports? {label:"Chocolates & Snacks",value:"Chocolates & Snacks",icon: require("../assets/CategoriesStack/chocolatesandSnacks.png")}, Maybe that what breaks it?

Comment: I have tested the above code and I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: even i cant repro this

Comment: I don't see any issue here *other than* the console log as an unintentional side-effect and React anti-pattern of storing passed props in local state. I don't see where any "extra" `""` are rendered or are an issue. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/an-array-of-objects-when-imported-in-react-native-gives-keys-and-values-in-doubl-0kd6tb). This seems to be an unreproducible issue.

Comment: Appology guys, you are right. the issue was coming due to passing of wrong icon data in Dropdownpicker  and I was linking it with extra commas .